# How can I improve the load time on Android WebViews that use JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, webview

I'm currently writing an app (runs completely offline) that uses HTML to display forms to the user in a WebView. I like using JQuery Mobile to write these forms, but when I use it the WebView takes about 3 seconds to load, which is too long for the app I'm using. This is on a Nexus S running Android 2.3.3.

I've investigated this issue a bit myself and it seems that the time is spent loading JQuery, JQuery Mobile, and their CSS files. Once the JS is loaded, rendering actually doesn't take all that long, I have very simple pages.

Since I use all these libraries for all forms that I show the user, is there a way to either keep the javascript in the RAM or use pre-loaded cache files to speed the loading of a JQuery Mobile HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

The WebView will automatically cache the files unless you have changed the default settings.

Make sure your files are on CDN. Make sure your CDN has reasonable TTL values set for the content items.

Comment: The files are all assets built into the app, so CDN isn't too much of a problem for me :). If I open a new HTML page in the app, will the cached JQuery javascript be loaded or will it reload it from source? I'm trying to get the pre-optimized cache used, since I think this will help... so far the speed doesn't look like the cache gets reused if I choose another page that also uses the same JQuery code.